# Campania Artercard from Pianura to Naples, Pompei, Vesuvius

Tags: italy, tips-and-tricks, naples

I'm going to visit Naples (Italy) and will stay there for three days. Right now I'm trying to figure out what kind of card/transportation is more suitable for me in terms of price.

I will live in the Pianura suburb of Naples and thinking about buying a Campania Artecard but not sure if there's any public transportation going from Pianura to the city center covered by this card. Also I'm planning to visit Pompeii and Vesuvius.

On [this website](http://www.campaniartecard.it/artecard/en/card/napoli-3-days) is written: "Travel on the public transport of the UNICOCAMPANIA Consortium to move within the urban area".

But I was unable to find any map of UNICOCAMPANIA Consortium transport connections.

Does Campania Artecard have any transport from Pianura suburb to the city center? Does it cover the way to Pompeii, Vesuvius?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UNICOCAMPANIA consortium [includes 14 public transport companies](http://unicocampania.it/index.php?lang=en&center=inside&colonna=consorzio&action=chisiamo):

> AIR, ANM, BUONOTOURIST, BUSITALIA Campania, CIAV, CLP, COSAT, CTP, DAV, EAV, SITA, TRENITALIA, TROTTA BUS SERVICE, AUTOLINEE CURCIO,  AUTOLINEE EREDI ARTURO LAMANNA,  ETTORE CURCIO & FIGLI, FRANCESCO & GIUSEPPE MANSI Snc

It seems that with Napoli card you can only travel around Naples city and suburbs. But you can buy a *Tutta la regione* Card which costs 11 Euro more and then you can travel all around Campania (including buses on islands Procida and Ischia, but not the ferry to them!) except Vesuvio for which you [have to pay 2,70 Euro one-way](http://unicocampania.it/index.php?lang=en&center=inside&colonna=turisti&action=vesuvio).

BTW on page that you linked, there is a link to pdf which explains on the first page what area you can travel  with this ticket.